# Batch command to exit process

Tags: windows, firefox, batch-file

I'm using firefox, and fequently get an error in flash player. This causes the browser to freeze up for some time, and usually it's faster to end the process "plugin-container.exe" from task manager. But it would be lovely if I just had a batch file on my desk that I could run to do this, is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`taskkill /F /IM plugin-container.exe`